# How do I reset Windows Emacs Tramp?

Tags: windows, emacs, tramp

Does Emacs Tramp on Windows store all of its information within the .emacs.d\tramp file, or are there other locations where it reads data upon startup? I want to completely reset all the information Emacs Tramp remembers as part of debugging how Tramp on Windows is behaving on my PC.

Answer (score 2):

Tramp reads cached data only from `~/.emacs.d/tramp`. Other packages might store Tramp related data, 'tho. Think about `recentf-mode`, for example.

If you call `emacs -Q`, Tramp recognises this, and doesn't read the data from this file. This is how I debug Tramp.

When Emacs runs already, you could clear Tramp's cache by calling `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections`.